# Woocommerce: show default variation price is products list?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there any way to force to show the price of the Product Variation I set as defaul in product page settings, instead of lower and higher prices?

I've got this code to show just one price, but the shown price is not the price of the default variation:

```
/*******************************
    SHOW ONLY ONE PRICE FOR VARIATIONS
*********************************/

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
     $price = '';
     $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());
     return $price;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279746/woocommerce-show-only-one-price-for-variable-product-on-discount

Comment: It's not, because in that function instead of the default variation, the lowest/discount price is shown.
Although it is a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453795/obtaining-default-variation-price-on-a-variation-product-woocommerce
I've tested this, and it works. I suspect that the op used this as a starting point (same function name and variables passed), but I'm not sure why it wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $selectedPrice = '';
    $dump = '';

    foreach ( $available_variations as $variation )
    {
        // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($variation['attributes'], true) . '</pre>';

        $isDefVariation=false;
        foreach($product->get_default_attributes() as $key=>$val){
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($key, true) . '</pre>';
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($val, true) . '</pre>';
            if($variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$key]==$val){
                $isDefVariation=true;
            }   
        }
        if($isDefVariation){
            $price = $variation['display_price'];         
        }
    }
    $selectedPrice = wc_price($price);

//  $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($available_variations, true) . '</pre>';

    return $selectedPrice . $dump;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I think your code only working for a single variation. I have updated code and added in below post

Answer (score 3):

This is solution for the minimal price as default for the variable products:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html','shop_variable_product_price', 10, 2 );

function shop_variable_product_price( $price, $product ){
    $variation_min_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);

    if(!empty($variation_min_reg_price)) {
        $price = woocommerce_price( $variation_min_reg_price );
    }
    else {
        $price = woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading @ Abhinav's code to show minimum price in case there is no default set:

```
/**
 * Show default variation price
 * If no default variation, shows min price
 */

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price($price, $product) {
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $selectedPrice = '';
    $dump = '';
    $defaultArray = array();
    foreach ($product->get_default_attributes() as $key => $val) {
        // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($key, true) . '</pre>';
        // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($val, true) . '</pre>';
        $defaultArray['attribute_' . $key] = $val;
    }
    // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($defaultArray, true) . '</pre>';
    if (empty($defaultArray)) {
        $price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ); // no default variation, show min price
    } else {
        foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($variation['attributes'], true) . '</pre>';
            $isDefVariation = false;
    
            $result = array_diff($defaultArray, $variation['attributes']);
            if (empty($result)) {
                $isDefVariation = true;
                $price = $variation['display_price'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $selectedPrice = wc_price($price);
    // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($available_variations, true) . '</pre>';
    return $selectedPrice . $dump;
}
```

Comment: What changes did you make exactly and why? Please [edit] your answer and add some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Show single variable price

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_variation_price', '__return_true' );
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrading @vivek's code as its code is only working for a single variation

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price($price, $product) {
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $selectedPrice = '';
    $dump = '';
    $defaultArray = array();
    foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {
    // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($variation['attributes'], true) . '</pre>';
    $isDefVariation = false;
    foreach ($product->get_default_attributes() as $key => $val) {
        // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($key, true) . '</pre>';
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($val, true) . '</pre>';
        $defaultArray['attribute_' . $key] = $val;
    }
    **$result = array_diff($defaultArray, $variation['attributes']);**
    **if (empty($result)) {
        $isDefVariation = true;
        $price = $variation['display_price'];
    }**
    }

    $selectedPrice = wc_price($price);
//  $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($available_variations, true) . '</pre>';
    return $selectedPrice . $dump;
}
```

This will work for multiple variation key